# What is the role of the for loop in this sorting function?

Tags: python, sorting, loops

I'm looking at this function while I try to learn different ways data is sorted, and I understand the main concept of it all including the while loop. The only thing I don't get is the role of the for loop on the first line of the function. Isn't the while loop doing the iterating and comparisons on the list? I tried taking the for loop out and as assumed the program failed to sort. It ran without error but simply returned the same list, unchanged. I guess I must not completely understand the sort if this doesn't make sense to me. So my question is: What is the role of the for loop in this sort function and what is it affecting each time through?

```
def selSort(L):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        minIndex = i
        minValue = L[i]
        j = i + 1
        while j < len(L):
            if minValue > L[j]:
                minIndex = j
                minValue = L[j]
            j += 1
        temp = L[i]
        L[i] = L[minIndex]
        L[minIndex] = temp
    return L

Q = [2, 8, 5, 9, 1, 15, 3, 7]
selSort(Q)
print Q
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 3, 5, 7, 8, 9, 15]
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_sort

Comment: You cannot sort an array in linear time. For every spot in the array you search the minimum in [1..N], [2..N], [3..N], [N,N] the while loop searches the minimum, the for loop makes it sort the array. If you only would need one while loop, you would have O(n)!

Comment: Neither of those help, I understand it is selection sort, hence the function name? And I was not asking about big O.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> [What is] the role of the `for` loop on the first line of the function. Isn't the `while` loop doing the iterating and comparisons on the list?

The `while` loop finds the right element *for one specific position in the list*, and the `for` loop repeats the search *for every position* (thereby sorting the list).

And all the `if` condition does is find the smallest element of those that haven't yet been placed. Thus on the first iteration of the `for` loop the algorithm will find the smallest element; on the second iteration, the second smallest; and so on.

Comment: Aha! So the while loop is simply swapping two elements that meet the if condition and then the for loop will do it again on the next element?

Comment: @Jordan: Pretty much. The while loop find the element that should go into position `i` and the for loop repeats that for every `i`.

Answer (score 0):

Selection sort "selects" the smallest element in a dataset and puts it at the beginning, then repeats on the rest of the list with the smallest element removed. Worded differently, at each step of selection sort, we move along each spot in the list and figure out what number should be at that spot in the list.

If we have the list `7 5 2 3 4 6 9 1 8`, then our first step would be to swap a `1` into the first place, a `2` into the second place, and so on. We don't have to worry about the very last spot in the list, because if we've taken everything else and put it in the right place, the last element will be in the right place because it's the only one left.

With this code, although it's not done as clearly, the outer for loop goes through every spot in the list, minus the last one (`len(L) - 1`). Once we go through the code inside the loop once, we'll have put the right number in the first spot, then we go again to try and fill the second spot, etc. Because we've put everything in the correct place for all of the spots before this one, we can assume that the correct thing in this spot will be the smallest item between this position and the end of the list, so, the while loop helps look for it. Then, we swap the two items.

This code is kind of messy, and it may make more sense if we reword the inner while loop to be a for loop:

```
def selSort(L):
    for i in range(len(L) - 1):
        minIndex = i
        minValue = L[i]
        for j in range(i + 1, len(L)):
            if minValue > L[j]:
                minIndex = j
                minValue = L[j]
        temp = L[i]
        L[i] = L[minIndex]
        L[minIndex] = temp
    return L
```